# Как сделать, чтобы cписок был  горизонтальным?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать, чтобы cписок был  горизонтальным?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(css)

```
li {
    float: left;
}
```

можно ещё

```
li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: можно использовать тогда float вместе с margin